# Change color with JButton, set the for loop terminating condition to infinite

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm doing a Coursework assignment for the Uni, the assignment is to create a RectanglesGUI with JPanel, but I have a problem with the buttons I have created.

The buttonSOUTH supposed to do the following:

When the user clicks on the JButton in the SOUTH region, the
rectangles filled with color1 should all change to a random Color,
while the rectangles filled with color2 should not change. A second
click on the JButton should make the rectangles filled with color2 all
change to a random Color, while the rectangles filled with a random
Color by the first click should stay the same Color. The user should be
able to continue clicking on the button indefinitely, and with each click
one set of rectangles will be filled with a random Color.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RectanglesGUI {

    JFrame frame;
    RectangleDrawPanel drawPanel;
    Color color1 = Color.orange;
    Color color2 = Color.blue;


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        RectanglesGUI gui = new RectanglesGUI();
        gui.go();
    }

    //this method sets up the JFrame
    public void go() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawPanel = new RectangleDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);

        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        CreateButton newButton = new CreateButton();
        newButton.CreateButton();
        frame.repaint();

    }

    // To Create a new Button
    public class CreateButton {

        JButton buttonSOUTH;
        JButton buttonNORTH;

        public void CreateButton () {
            buttonSOUTH = new JButton("Change Colors");
            buttonSOUTH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
            buttonSOUTH.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(buttonSOUTH, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            buttonSOUTH.addActionListener(new RandomColorListener());

            buttonNORTH = new JButton("Reset Colors");
            buttonNORTH.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
            buttonNORTH.setVisible(true);
            frame.add(buttonNORTH, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            buttonNORTH.addActionListener(new ResetListener());
        }

        // ActionListener for buttonSOUTH
        private class ResetListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                color1 = Color.orange;
                color2 = Color.blue;
                frame.repaint();
            }
        }

        // ActionListener for buttonNORTH
        private class RandomColorListener implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ChangeColor c = new ChangeColor();

                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
                    if (i % 2 == 0) {
                        color1 = c.getColor1();
                        frame.repaint();
                    } else {
                        color2 = c.getColor2();
                        frame.repaint();
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // Change Color Class
        private class ChangeColor {

            private Color getColor1(){
                Random fill1 = new Random();
                color1 = new Color (fill1.nextInt(256), fill1.nextInt(256),
                        fill1.nextInt(256));
                return color1;
            }

            private Color getColor2(){
                Random fill2 = new Random();
                color2 = new Color (fill2.nextInt(256), fill2.nextInt(256),
                        fill2.nextInt(256));
                return color2;
            }
        }
    }

    class RectangleDrawPanel extends JPanel {
        public void paintComponent (Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2=(Graphics2D)g;
            int width = getWidth();
            int height = getHeight();

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    int x = (getWidth() / 5) * i;
                    int y = (getHeight() / 5) * j;
                    if ((i % 2) == (j % 2)) {
                        g2.setColor(color1);
                    } else
                        g2.setColor(color2);
                    g2.fill3DRect(x,y,width,height,true);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to set this to be infinite

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
     if (i % 2 == 0) {
         color1 = c.getColor1();
         frame.repaint();
      } 
      else {
          color2 = c.getColor2();
          frame.repaint();
      }
}
```

Comment: If you don't put anything in the test expression part (delete the `i < 100` and just have it empty), that makes the for-loop infinite.

Comment: I tired that, once I click on the button the loop execution continues and the program hang till I terminate it (I think that is normal with for-loop infinite) ,  but what I really need is to switch between color1 and color2 every time I click the button without limitation (which is 100 here) I could set it to 999999999 but how to make it infinite?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood. Do you mean you can only click the button 100 times with the current code?

Comment: yes that what I meant, maybe I used the wrong loop here to implement that, but I didn't find other way than using loop to switch between the colors every time I click the button witch has the termination condition . maybe you or someone have a better idea for that

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't have a problem with it being infinite. If you set 100 to 2, your code will still work, your user will still be able to click the buttons indefinitely.

Comment: well... it works, but now I'm confused because I didn't understand

Comment: how the loop is working

Comment: Every time actionPerformed() is called, the i=0 part also runs, and 0 is always less than 100 (or 2).

Comment: Self-contradictory: "A second click on the JButton should make the rectangles filled with color2 all change to a random Color, while the rectangles filled with a random Color by the first click should stay the same Color." If the 2nd half is ok then the 1st half intends rectangles *initially* filled with color2. Unclear: "with each click one set of rectangles will be filled with a random Color" It doesn't say for click n what its set *is*. The whole paragraph apparently should just be: On click n, all and only rectangles initially filled with color n = 1 mod 2 change to a common random color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this part `for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)`
is not useful for checking.
both part inside condition checking will always executed. that mean both color2 and color1 will change. since i%2 will return 0 and 1

add this property to RectangleGui class `boolean status=false;`
then change code inside method actionPerformed in class RandomColorListener to:

```
 if (status) {
      color1 = c.getColor1();
      frame.repaint();
 } else {
      color2 = c.getColor2();
      frame.repaint();
 }
  status=!status;
```

Comment: I tired that before but it didn't work with me because I added the line "boolean status=false;" in the "actionPerformed" not in the "RandomColorListener"

Comment: i mean add boolean status=false to RectangleGui class not RandomColorListener Class. but both will work...

Comment: yes I do, it works thank you so much, I'm new here, do I have to do something with this post to close it?